Older HP computer only recognizing HD or CD drive for startup not recognizing USB so I can install windows, ican I add The USB to the startup menu?
I found an older HP in the garage, put a new hard drive in it and decided to give it to my grandson.
I went into the boot menu and it will only recognize the hard drive and the DVD. I was hoping to install Windows using the jump drive, any suggestions? I really don't want to spend the money to buy a bunch of 8.5 gig CDs for this one project.

Older computers often are unable to boot from USB (mass storage) drivers. You may try an workaround with PLoP: https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/plpbt.bin.html#runcd (Download, extract and burn the ISO in a regular CD-R or CD-RW, boot from it with your Windows/Linux/Other USB installer already connected and you'll have a menu with an option to chainload to the USB drive). But honestly there are lots of thing wrong with your approach: 1. Any PC so old to not have an option to boot from USB sticks is likely to NOT support any current Windows version (Win11 is out of the question, obviously) ...

... Win10 has support until next year so it isn't an option either. Some very light LINUX distro can be an option but the usability of even that is questionable if the CPU doesn't have the instructions required for modern, current, internet. 2. I have a serious issue with your philosophy of "give the old crap to the kids". Well-intentioned it might be, at the end of the day it's very stupid. Kids need newer and more powerful computers just for the typical daily usage; you, OTOH, might do fine with old hardware (again, provided it at least has the instructions required for modern internet).

A long shot question -  did you have a USB plugged in when you attempted to boot the drive?   Chances are that if there was not a USB drive installed when you turned it on it would not have given it as an option.

my 2 cents:
you mention you went into boot menu, but I was wondering is, by any chance, you have also verified if the bios has another different option to enable the boot from USB (BTW: in these cases reporting the actual laptop model may be of help)

All these comments so far have good and helpful information. Please update your question indicating answers to the questions posed so that we can better narrow down on a solution for you.
